# Is there any detectable difference between Browser and programmatic http requests

Tags: httpwebrequest, screen-scraping

Is there any way to tell from headers or other data, whether a request is from a browser or non-browser program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser *is* a programmatic HTTP request.
It just happens to have a user in front of it.

Some programmatic HTTP requests won't include a `User-Agent` header, though.

---

You could do something fancy, such as sending recorded mouse movements using Javascript and checking them statistically, and the non-browser client can simulate them.

Or you could just use a CAPTCHA.

Comment: i guess i should say non-browser

Comment: There is no difference between a browser and a nonbrowser.

Answer (score 2):

You could unreliably guess by inspecting user agent and referrer, but both are easily spoofed.

Best way is to use some form of CAPTCHA. That is what they were made to do, differentiate between humans and automated actions.